# How to split with comma and data missing

Tags: sql, asp.net

[My Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpe7U.png)

```
set rsGetAcc = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
sSQL = "select accno, referral, "
sSQL = sSQL & "refer1, refer2, refer3, refer4, refer5, refer6 from member "
sSQL = sSQL & "where refer3 = '" & session("username") & "' "
sSQL = sSQL & "and refer4 = '' "
sSQL = sSQL & "and type = 'CSH' "
rsGetAcc.open sSQL, conn
if not rsGetAcc.eof then
     set rstChkBalance = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
     sSQL = "SELECT ifnull(sum(if(sign='+',amount,0)),0) as TotMBCashLmtDB FROM trns "
     **sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE accno IN ('" & rsGetAcc("accno") & "') "**
     sSQL = sSQL & "AND type = 'ASD' "
     sSQL = sSQL & "AND api = '' "
     rstChkBalance.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3
     if not rstChkBalance.eof then
         dTotMBCashLmtDB = rstChkBalance("TotMBCashLmtDB")
     end if
end if
pCloseTables(rsGetAcc)
```

My DB show two accno but my rsGetaAcc("accno") only have 1 accno
in **sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE accno IN ('" & rsGetAcc("accno") & "') "**

Please Teach Me how to get 2 accno and how to split into ("TKSS1S1MB2", "TKSS1S1M4")

Thank You.

Comment: If the 1st recordset isnt of any use other than using it for 2nd recordset, would combining the query help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 set rstChkBalance = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
 sSQL = "SELECT ifnull(sum(if(sign='+',amount,0)),0) as TotMBCashLmtDB FROM trns "
 sSQL = sSQL & "WHERE accno IN (select accno from member "
 sSQL = sSQL & "where refer3 = '" & session("username") & "' "
 sSQL = sSQL & "and refer4 = '' "
 sSQL = sSQL & "and type = 'CSH') "
 sSQL = sSQL & "AND type = 'ASD' "
 sSQL = sSQL & "AND api = '' "
```

Note that I have included the query of 1st recordset into `IN` clause of 2nd recordset.

Comment: tq i know why =)